# UICollectionView Autolayout & number of items in a row

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a query regarding `UICollectionView`.

I have a customcell suclass for `UICollectionViewCell`. Each cell contains 1 imageview, a progressbar & two labels. I am able to display all the data in UICollectionView using custom cell.

Now my query is:- How can I show only one item in a row if I am running in 4-inch devices & display two items in a row if running in iPhone 6 & 6s? Moreover all the items is a `UICollectionViewCell` should get arranged.

I know that I can use size classes but would be good if any one have better idea than this approach.

Comment: what about implementing the UICollectionView Delegate method for returning size based on the current device calculate the cellSize as per device width

Comment: What spacing do you want around the cells? Were you anticipating that the single-column cells would be the same size as the two-column cells, or do the columns stretch to fit the width they're in?

Comment: @stefandouganhyde no single column cell would not be  same size of two column cell.

Comment: It would be useful to know what you wanted it to look like in both cases. My answer is design-dependent. Also, are you using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or a custom layout?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this as per your requirement,put conditions for devices

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float cellWidth = screenWidth / 2.0;  //put number of columns you require
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

    return size;
}
```